# How to make Spring-remoting work over Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-remoting

Is there any example (somewhere) of spring-remoting working on top of (spring-) Kafka ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Kafka implementation of spring-remoting.

`spring-remoting` itself is deprecated as of Spring Framework 5.3.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/d9ccd618ea9cbf339eb5639d24d5a5fabe8157b5

You can, however, use the RPC support in Spring for Apache Kafka

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#replying-template