# Error while calling a remote service via Spring HTTPInvoker from my Kafka consumer

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, httprequest, kafka-consumer-api, spring-remoting

Getting the "No thread-bound request found" issue when calling a remote service via Spring HTTPInvoker from my Kafka
Consumer. In this case ideally there would not be a Http Request as the data comes to Consumer from another
MQ System. Anyway I tried setting the RequestContextListener, but still not working.. Anybody tried this approach? How to
achieve Spring-remoting with Kafka Listeners.

Comment: Please share code and complete stacktrace in a [mcve]

Comment: Also, mentioned here that Spring remoting is deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/a/65996407/2308683